# reallocing array of structs gives error - invalid next size

Tags: c, struct, realloc

I am writting a program that creates an array of structs (dynamically allocated). The code works until the array needs to be enlarged and even after checking everything I could think of and trying all sorts of tips from SO, it doesn't seem to work. None of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789126/how-to-realloc-an-array-of-structs), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995441/realloc-invalid-next-size), [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657474/realloc-invalid-next-size-core-dumped) or [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750219/c-why-realloc-isnt-working) solved it.

Here is the problematic part of code:

```
    struct distance {
    ...;
}   *dist;


int     main        ( void )
{
    unsigned int len_max      = 128;
    unsigned int current_size = len_max * sizeof(distance);
    unsigned int distN        = 0;       //counter
    dist = (distance*) malloc(sizeof(distance*) * len_max);  
    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
        for(unsigned int l = k+1; l < i; l++)
        {
            if(distN*sizeof(distance) >= current_size) // bug here?
            {
                current_size = 2*(distN) * sizeof(distance*);
                dist = (distance*)realloc(dist, current_size);
            } 
            //... do stuff
            distN++;
        }    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:
1) I know `x = realloc (x, ...)` is a BAD practise, but this will be running in a school testing environment with no error handling options, so there is no point in making a tmp_ptr.
2) I also know that casting a malloc and realloc is not the cleanest approach, but again, it is a rigid school testing environment for C course and it compiles with `g++`. This way the compiler doesn't give me warnings.

EDIT: The code compiles, runs without issue when reallocation isn't needed. Once the input data exceeds memory allocated by malloc, this shows:

```
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: `g++` is a c++ compiler. Use `gcc` to compiler for c. The description "doesn't seem to work" is very vague. What does it mean "doesn't seem to work"? How do you detect that something "does not work"? Does it compile? Does it run? Does it set your pc on fire? Please don't describe that it does not work, rather _show_ what happens, when it happens and what would you like to happen. Note how you mix `sizeof(distance*)` with `sizeof(distance)` - maybe do not store the size, but rather store the _count_ of elements in the array, and multiply it by the size in re-/m-alloc

Comment: `distance*` isn't C, which needs to be `struct distance*`.

Comment: `invalid next size`. realloc itself is not giving that error. The most probable reason is that there is memory corruption in your code. It could be anywhere in your code and is likely not in the part that you have shown. So we cannot really help unless you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual allocation is for array of pointers, not array of structs. If you want to make room for say n `distance` objects, you should call `malloc( sizeof(distance) * n)` while all I can see is `malloc( sizeof(distance*) ...)`. As your struct is probably greater in size than a pointer, there is not enough memory allocated.

Side note: realloc in double loop is bad idea. Try to do the math first, and use realloc only, if truly needed.

Comment: thanks I will try to meddle with malloc, too. Although thinking about it, even though malloc maths there is probably wrong, it shouldn't give the error (works fine for few entries).

Double loop is there because of the `//...stuff here` part (nothing really happens in the first loop, just counting indexes on two different places). But I will try to think it through thorouhgly in the morning. Thanks for pointing it out.